# Call stack API for flexible datatype items in C

Tags: c, api, stack

The problem here is to design an API for the call stack in C. The items to be pushed onto the stack can be of different sizes, ranging from 1 byte to N bytes (and can be a mixture of them- for example, push a char first, then push an int, then push a struct). The stack can be a implemented as a linked list or dynamic array, there are no constraints.

My solution: 
Since the datatype of the item that will be pushed onto the stack is unknown, I figured that using a void* pointer might be a suitable solution.

Question: 
Is this the best way of implementing it, from an engineering perspective? Is there a better approach? Please find my code below. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct stack_node snode;
struct stack_node{
    snode *next;
    void *data;
};

bool push(snode **top, void* data)
{
    snode *current = (snode*)malloc(sizeof(snode));
    if(!current)
        return false;
    current->data = data;
    current->next = *top;
    *top = current;
    return true;
}

bool pop(snode **top, void **data)
{
    snode* current;
    current = *top;
    if(!current)
        return false;
    *data = current->data;
    *top = current->next;
    free(current);
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    int num=0, i;
    snode* top = NULL;

    int arr[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    for(i = 0; i < 10 ; i++ )
    {
        if(!push(&top, &arr[i]))
            printf("error allocating memory\n");
    }
    void *data;
    while(pop(&top, &data))
    {
        printf("popped %d\n", *((int*)data));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One drawback I see in your implementation is you don't store information about how a data inserted onto the stack should be interpreted i.e if it is of type struct A, double or int. In your case you know it is int. And your implementation assumes consumer knows what he is getting out by popping from stack.

Comment: Precisely. What will be the best way of handling this? Any suggestions?

Comment: I think your implementation is good enough for those cases were you keep it up to consumers to access what data is all about. If you keep your stack scope for just one type of data members i.e either all elements are A type or all elements are B type, then in addition to top we can have say type field with enum values as INT, DOUBLE, STRUCT_A (enum defined earlier). Via these consumers can get to know the type. If you increase the scope to mix of members then each element can have a type (with all possible values). If a user can know about the type then he obviously knows length as well. :)

Comment: Between in place of **top you can use *top as well. It saves some indirections and address of uses.

Comment: @rakesh.pandit  Pushing and popping will modify stack head, hence we HAVE to use the **top ??? Thanks for the enum insight. That could be a possible way of doing it.

Comment: Yes you need a top. My point was you can use snode * as top. That will avoid &top and *top usage.

Comment: @rakesh.pandit using struct mix{ union{ int ival; float fval; char cval; double dval; void *ptrval;}u; size_t size; }; is a bad idea. The reason is it will take up more data than required. Stacks for programming language are made of 1byte per block structure. Hence `unsigned char` is the only way forward.

Comment: @Aniket I disagree. void* data pointer has advantages as well as disadvantages. Size isn't the only feature/constraint stack implementations need to worry about. Neither does question says it has any constraints to deal with. How do you propose unsigned char (single byte) keep links between them ? They will use pointers unless it is a static array of chars which has its own limitations.

Comment: @rakesh.pandit Imagine you were writing a stack for a programming language(this is the constraint), and you wanted to push data onto the stack(not pointers to data) why would you use `void*`?

Comment: @Aniket void * allows me to point to a data area irrespective of what the type is. Question says data to be pushed can be of different size (and a mix of them as well). If you push a single char, you may have to keep a note of how many pushes belong to a data type (e.g for a sturct with size 6 you have to pop 6 times) etc. That is why I said earlier that depending on what features a stack wants to implement, implementations can differ. unsigned char isn't the only way forward.

Comment: @rakesh.pandit you still didnot understand the meaning of requiring 'data' on stack. `(void*)` will have to point to the stack data anyway. And yes, since he is implementing a stack for programming language, which means he is implementing a virtual machine. You CAN add back the bytes to stack-pointer. Anyways this isn't the language issue, its a VM issue.

Comment: @Aniket I disagree on both your explanation (it seems to be flawed) and your assumption that I didn't understood the meaning of 'data'. Question says the requirement is to implement a stack API. Not a stack for programming language in a virtual machine, even though that is fine as well, but I disagree with your argument here. I wouldn't be able continue further. Thank you for your quick responses.

Comment: thanks for the discussion guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a pointer would be a good option if the data wasn't suppose to exist on the stack. What if I want to pass more than 4 bytes of data from stack? pointer would not be the best option there. In my opinion you should insert data byte by byte onto the stack. Which means `unsigned char` would be a good option as well.

Comment: Yes that does make sense. But that would present an additional problem of having the bytes popped in a reverse order- for example, an int will pushed first--->last byte, and while popping it, it will come out last-->first byte. Any way of handling that elegantly?

Comment: Additionally, while popping a char, how would the user know which datatype is being popped? For example, the user might want to pop just the last element pushed. Supposed that element was a N byte stuct- how would he know how many bytes to pop? Perhaps one solution is to have a count of total bytes and the present byte's number in the struct?

Comment: well there is a way to handle that but it will depend on your VM implementation @piscianemperor